# Can I install a light switch/GFCI outlet combo?

Tags: electrical, lighting, receptacle, gfci

Hi I'm trying to see if I can install a light switch/ GFCI outlet combo here.

If not what are other options or alternatives.

This is the current situation:

[image]

This is what I want to use[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it yet and was there a problem ?

Comment: What does the room have *now* for receptacles?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a switch loop. That is, a hot white coming down from a fixture to the switch and a black load wire going back to control a fixture. Since there is no neutral, you can't wire an outlet to the existing box with the existing wires. If you verify this to be true, put a few wraps of black tape over the white wire or mark it with a black magic marker to indicate that it's hot. You would have to replace the 14/2 with a 14/3 to bring the neutral down from the source to add the GFCI outlet.